# SQLEXPRESS: Suitability for Production Websites for Read Mostly Data

Tags: performance, web-applications, sql-server-express

Has anybody used a local instance of SQLEXPRESS on a web server for serving up read only/mostly content?  It seems a read-only database with no referential integrity, denormalized tables, indexes galore, etc. could perform well.  Is this a completely horrible idea?  And if so, why?

Answer (score 1):

Very similar question already in SO [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/180537/sql-express-for-production)

check the comparison features [here](http://www.microsoft.com/Sqlserver/2005/en/us/compare-features.aspx)

Quick answer is: no real issue.